# c# using TinyUrl Api(getting original address from shortened address)

Tags: c#

i found the tinyurl api to  shorten the Url. you can see from the link below.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bramveen/2009/01/06/converting-url-to-tinyurl-in-c/

And I also want to get original address from my shortened url.

but i can't find that reverse api.

anyone knows how to reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the api there is no api to get the reverse. But all tinyurl is doing when you send a HTTP request to tiny url is return a HTTP 301 with the original url in the Location response header. So you could do something like this.

```
// Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now you can use the response object to read the location header value (which is your original url).